# Facebook Like button unclickable

Tags: facebook, web-applications

I've decided to add a Like button to one of pages on my website.
The button appears, but it can't be clicked (i.e. nothing happens)

I've tried both *iframe* and *XFBML* with different settings, but nothing helped.

[Here](http://blaxpirit.org.ua/content/test.php) is an example of not working button

What can I do to fix the problem?

Additional information can be provided if needed, just write a comment.

Answer (score 1):

The code on your site doesn't look like the code that is generated using the [like button generator](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like). Have you used the generator? It looks like you're mixing and matching two different ways of producing the box. Also, in your script tag, you have a line that says: `'your app id'`.  I would imagine that you would have to change that to something meaningful.

Comment: I don't have any *app id*. Changed back to *iframe*, but that also doesn't work.

Comment: And that page is just a test. I did use the *like button generator*, I just had to include *Facebook SDK*

Comment: Did you try filling out the generator and getting the code from that? Also, do you have JavaScript enabled?

Comment: Try it without the SDK.

Comment: *XFBML* way cannot work without the SDK. Currently at the example page (in the question) there is *iframe* way: the code from the generator.

Comment: It looks like you're not putting your full URL in. Try the full URL, not just the domain root.

Comment: What do you think "http%3A%2F%2Fblaxpirit.org.ua%2Fts2" is, then?

Comment: That's only the domain encoded. You have to enter the full URL including the page, which ends up looking like this: http%3A%2F%2Fblaxpirit.org.ua%2Fcontent%2Ftest.php

Comment: Initially the button was on the */ts2* page, but it doesn't work there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The error I see right off the bat is that you are trying to use the FBML tags (Example, fb:like). They can only be used within a Facebook application.

Try this... http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like